# Detect which UI was clicked with its name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I detect which UI was clicked with its gameObject's name? I am using PointerEvents and this script works if I attach it to each of my `RawImage, Image and other components`. I want to make this script global so that it shows which UI was clicked. How do I do this?

```
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 using UnityEngine; // 1

 public class PointerUI : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler // 2
     , IDragHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
 // ... And many more available!
 {

     void Update () {

     }

     public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData) // 3
     {
         Debug.Log ("I was clicked");
     }

     public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData) {
         Debug.Log ("I'm being dragged!");
     }

     public void OnPointerEnter (PointerEventData eventData) {
         Debug.Log ("I enter");
     }

     public void OnPointerExit (PointerEventData eventData) {
         Debug.Log ("I exit");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Unity doesn't directly provide this feature. You likely won't get around setting a script to every clickable object (without it getting complicated by automatically adding scripts).

However you can globalize the processing of the clicks the following way:
Create your global instance and apply the "Singleton pattern" to make it accessible from any script (basically a public static variable that holds a reference to the actual instance).
Give this script a function like:

```
void NotifyAboutClick(GameObject clicked_object)
```

Then write a script very similar to your existing one that is applied to every clickable UI element and in the OnPointerClick etc. functions call the NotifyAboutClick(game_object); function through the static reference of your global object.